# How do you reply to a question without adding an answer?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I know that you can answer a question by filling out the "Add An Answer" form and clicking submit, but how do I just reply to the question with a request for more information?  I noticed that other people can do it, but I must be blind or something, because I don't see a "reply" button anywhere.

I'm using Chrome on OS X.

Comment: What's the reasoning for the rep requirement? Catching spam in comments would be harder?

Comment: BTW-- The 50 rep limit does not apply to *your own* questions.

Comment: @dotnetchris: Actually, catching spam in comments is harder, because it doesn't bump the question to the top. Comments are also harder to see, which is more of a factor in larger questions/answers with more comments, which show the "show more comments" button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the Add Comment feature, and you need 50 reputation to do that.  See the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Add Comment" link right below the original question.